# Does a user receive a notification if I ping them in a comment which I delete immediately after?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

How does it show up on the other one's account when I post a comment and then delete it again?

I am talking about comments that trigger a notification, whether right under the question/answer, or with `@username`.

Sometimes I have to reply, because the other user had an "obvious" misconception, I had to point out. The worst thing would be to ignore it; then the other user's *fopa* (if this was a comment, I'd be glad someone would write a comment that it is spelled *faux-pax*, and then delete it after I corrected it) would be permanent. But we both then revised/delete our comments. I always waited till the other user reacted.

My real question: Can I delete that comment right away, and count on him getting the notification? Or is the notification also deleted with deleting the comment, as if I never posted that comment?

Comment: I really think this one should have been asked before, but I could not find it, who ever finds it gets a "thx" comment from me, that i will immediately delete after i posted it.

Comment: Actually it's spelt [faux pas](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/faux-pas)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you can’t count on them getting the notification.

If you delete the comment the notification will be removed. I'm pretty sure that at a couple of times I experienced notifications "lingering", probably as an result of cache, but those where exceptions to the rule. Normally, they should go away.

If the user is online, they may get to see the notification for an instant. If you delete it quickly enough, they'll get the red marker in their inbox for a short time, but upon opening the inbox, there will be nothing to read (and the notification marker should fade to nothingness as well, even without any action on the user's part).

And if they have the mobile app installed, they may be able to see it, since the notification will remain in their phone's "notification center". If the notification is short enough they may even get to read it there. But if they attempt to open the notification (and open the app), it will go away permanently.

Comment: `if you delete it quick enough they'll get the red marker in their inbox, but on opening the inbox there will be nothing to read.` Actually, the red marker will go away as soon as the message gets deleted and the other user's browser gets the update via the websocket. (I've seen this happen quite a few times)

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Here I actually know how that part works: the icon on the top-bar in the browser is only updated once in a while by an ajax request (like those "new comment", "an edit was made" and other thinks that happen without clicking a link). but additional content that was not there before (e.g the additional comments, when you click the "X more comments" link) including the actual content of the inbox; those are loaded from the sever after you click.

Comment: There is a slight caveat to this, notifications from the mobile app can linger for a longer time, especially if the post was deleted before the comment was deleted.

Comment: @Sam No, it's not an ajax request, it's using websockets (maybe SignalR?) so the notifications aren't polled every "once in a while".

Comment: @DavidG so it is just the server that only replies on the websocket "once in a while"? Because It definitely was not even close to real-time when I checked, but that was a long time ago, so maybe now it is.

Comment: we do get notification on mobile even if the comment is deleted

Comment: not only on mobile... also happening on desktop (firefox)